# Why is there no "autumntime" or "falltime"?

Tags: word-choice, etymology, nouns, is-it-a-word, seasons

Why is "autumntime" (or "falltime") not a word?

- wintertime => sure
- springtime => fine
- summertime => lovely

But apparently autumn/fall has no equivalent. Why?

Comment: There's *"harvesttime"*.

Comment: In Portugal it is common to misuse the stations, as some people, specially rural and elder people seem not to know what Autumn (Outuno) and Spring (Primavera) are. They only use Winter (Inverno) and Summer (Verão).

Comment: My mother use to always sing ["It's Autumntime"](https://www.lds.org/music/library/childrens-songbook/its-autumntime?lang=eng)

Comment: @sergiol Well, the ancient romans didn't care either. The other seasons only become important as you go to the colder climates, like northern France and Germany. I'd guess that's why the Julian calendar was designed by Julius - conquering the northern territories, a better calendar was needed (farming was trivial in southern europe compared to the north).

Comment: Fall season is quite short, so it is not enough TIME to call it time.

Comment: The answer is simple. Autumntime could become a word if people used it more. All you have to do is use it in a sentence as often as possible and hope that it catches on.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

The Anglo-Saxon calendar only had two seasons, *winter* and *summer*, each six months long. They had words for other periods of the year, but they weren't considered seasons.

At some point near the beginning of Middle English<sup>1</sup>, a four-season calendar was adopted. However, the other two seasons didn't have definite names. We can see from the OED that their names fluctuated for a while before settling into *spring* and *fall* or *autumn*.

> c1050:  *Þa feower timan..lengten, sumor, hærfest, & winter.*
>
> a1387: *Þe evenes of þe day and þe nyȝt is ones in þe Lente and efte in hervest.*
>
> 1545:  *Spring tyme, Somer, faule of the leafe, and winter.*

It seems from these quotes that we might easily have had *lent* (a shortened form of *lengthen*) and *harvest* as names for *spring* and *autumn*, as these were common names for these seasons in Middle English.

It also appears that the *"long forms"* of the names for the seasons were *"spring time"*, *"harvest time"*, and *"fall of the leaf"*. This explains why we don't say *"fall time"*.

The word *"autumn"* was borrowed from Old French in the 16th century, well after *"springtime"*, *"summertime"*, *"harvesttime"*, and *"wintertime"* were established, and for some reason these phrases were not extended to *"autumntime"*, even though it would have been a very logical development in English. Maybe people used *"spring time"* and *"harvest time"* more often earlier because *"spring"* and *"harvest"* weren't yet established words for seasons (as *"summer"* and *"winter"* were).

<sup>1</sup> This probably didn't happen at a single point in time. The quote from the OED ca. 1050 lists four seasons. However, the song *"Sumer Is Icumen In"*, which Wikipedia says was composed in the 13th century, is clearly about spring.

Comment: In the second quotation at least, *Lente* is surely the church season rather than 'lengthen'. Not that it changes anything in a very clear answer.

Comment: @TimLymington Possibly. Lent got its name from the season, however, and not the other way around.

Comment: @Tim: because it's capitalized? You might be right, although the OED doesn't think so. But either way, the church season was named for the calendar season, which was the older usage. Compare Dutch, where spring is *"lente"* and Lent is *"vasten"*.

Comment: I’m no longer certain that the premise of the original question is correct, in that I do find examples of *autumntime* (or *autumn-time* or *autumn time*) starting around the mid-1800s. It was used by DH Lawrence and Oscar Wilde, but it is certainly not a common word.

Comment: @tchrist I possibly should have said "in the various dictionaries I've checked" in the question. Yes, I found examples, but as you pointed out in another comment they are far less frequent, and in the dictionaries I checked, *wintertime*, *springtime* and *summertime* were all listed as unhyphenated words, but none of them listed *autumntime*. Having said all of that, the question originally occurred to me randomly when I realized I had often heard people use the other terms and never heard *autumntime*.

Comment: @CupawnTae Compound words vary in whether they are open compounds, hyphenated ones, or just glommed together without ado.  The longer something has been used, the more likely it is to be written with adornment “nowadays” — as a case in point. Early nineteenth century uses favor *autumn time*, while late nineteenth and early twentieth uses favor *autumn-time*. These days it’s most commonly encountered as *autumntime* — if it’s even encountered at all. Also understand the UK publishers nearly always favor more hyphenation in such cases than North American ones tend to use.

Comment: [Related](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/88484).

Comment: "Lent" and "harvest" are still used in some languages for these seasons. For example, Dutch has "lente" for spring and "herfst" for autumn, While German calls autumn "der Herbst".

Comment: Fascinating. I think I shall start using "harvest-time" in my speech.

Comment: The Anglo-Saxons write of *Ðæt gewrixle ðara feower tyda ðæt is lencten and sumer and herfest and winter* "the change of the four seasons, that is spring and summer and autumn and winter". See **hærfest** in Bosworth-Toller *An Anglo-Saxon Dictionary* (Oxford).

Comment: @TRomano: [Bede](http://www.wyrdwords.vispa.com/heathenry/calendar.html) (673-735) says: *"Originally they [the heathen English] divided the year into two seasons, summer and winter, assigning the six months in which the days are longer than the nights to summer, and the other six to winter. Hence, they called the month in which the winter season began "Winterfilleth", a name made up of "winter" and "full Moon", because winter began on the first full moon of that month."* So I should probably should have said the "pre-Christian Anglo-Saxon Calendar".

Comment: *"It also appears that the "long forms" of the names for the seasons were "spring time", "harvest time", and "fall of the leaf". This explains why we don't say "fall time"."* This explains nothing. Can't we have >1 term for something?

Comment: OMG, thanks so much @PeterShor! Being German the name "Herbst" for autumn was always _just that_: a name. But with the first and second examples it was _immediately_ evident where the German name comes from. As a native speaker I have wondered about many a word (and researched them), but for "Herbst" _this_ was my Euraka-moment. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @Nzall fun fact. German also has an older name for spring: [Lenz](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Lenz) (der Lenz, masc.).

Comment: @TimLymington not [if Wiktionary is to be believed](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Lenz). According to that it traces its roots back to "long".

Answer (score 55):

**TL;DR**:

1. The premise that *autumntime* “is not a word” is faulty: it is a word.
2. Unlike most dictionaries, the OED does include ***autumn-time***.
3. It is quite **rare** in comparison with the other seasons’ versions.
4. Variations in punctuation, spacing, and capitalization **do not matter**.

<sub>This answer is not meant to detract from Peter Shor’s, which I believe is both correct and insightful is its explanation of why *autumntime* occurs so rarely compared with the other three modern seasons.</sub>

---

Well, there is the word ***autumn-tide***, but it doesn’t get used much. Here’s one OED citation for it:

> **1870 Morris** *Earthly Par.* I. ii. 485 ― The changing year came round to autumn-tide.

This is the sense of *tide* that is equivalent to *time*, as in *eventide* or *yuletide*.

The OED’s sense 13 for *time* not only equates it to *tide* but even goes so far as to offer up the otherwise-absent ***autumn-time*** as one example:

> - **13a.** A point in the course of time or of a period: = ***tide*** *sb.*<sup>3</sup> ; spec. in early ME., the hour of the day; = OE.
>     *tíd*: see ***tide***
>     *sb.*<sup>4</sup> [. . .]
> - **13b.** A point or fixed part of the year, a season, as in ***time of year***; in comb. in *spring-time*,
>     *summer-time*, ***autumn-time***, *winter-time*; also *term-time*, *vacation-time*, *holiday-time*, etc.; also, of a day,
>     as *time of day*, *time of night*,
>     *day-time*, *night-time*, *morning-time*,
>     *evening-time*; also *dinner-time*,
>     *bed-time*, etc.; also, a point in the moon’s age.

However, the OED includes no actual citations for *autumn-time*.

As I recently mentioned [elsewhere](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/185262/), it is important to remember that **no** dictionary purports to include **all** words, not even the OED. Just because a dictionary doesn’t list a word does **not** mean that that word is “not a word”: absence of evidence never constitutes evidence of absence.

There are many reasons why dictionaries leave words out. You should therefore never conclude that the omission of a dictionary entry for a word somehow “means” that that word is not an “actual” word.

On the other hand, just because a dictionary does happen to list a word does not necessarily mean that it is a common word that most native speakers will know what means.

In this particular case, we have a fairly uncommon word that nonetheless has a clear meaning that any native speaker would immediately recognize upon first seeing or hearing it.  They just might think it a bit odd.

---

## Citations

In tracking down literary citations for documentation of actual usage, I noticed that an unusually high proportion seemed to be in verse.  This may be nothing more than a seasonal thread running through poetry.

In any event, instances of *autumntime* (including as an open compound *autumn time* or a hyphenated one *autumn-time*) are outnumbered by the other seasons by a factor of **two to three orders of magnitude** depending on the season.

One really must not consider those three forms different “words”.  They aren’t; **they are merely different ways of writing the same word.**  Similarly, the capitalization doesn’t matter either. First of all, the seasons were often capitalized in older prose.  But also because poets like to personify the seasons and therefore capitalize them, although this practice is rare in current prose.

### *Fall time,  fall-time*, and  *falltime*

The word *fall-time* (no matter its spelling) is even less frequent than *autumn-time*, occurring too infrequently to try to assign relative frequencies.   It also seems to be something of a North American regionalism, at least today. In particular, it surfaces in many accounts of the Yukon and Alaska, some of which I reference below.

It is interesting that all three of *spring-time, harvest-time, fall-time* occur in the Douglass citation, which being the oldest is the first one listed immediately below.

> 1. I do not remember to have ever met a slave who could tell his birhday. They seldom come nearer to it than planting-time, harvest-time, cherry-time, spring-time, or **fall-time**. A want of information concerning my own was a source of unhappiness to me even during childhood. The white children could tell their ages. I could not tell why I ought to be deprived of the same privilege.
>      
>          ―*Narrative of the Life of Frederick Douglass, An American Slave*, Frederick Douglass, **‎1845**
> 2. Come to be dreaminess
>      come to see me soon and see me
>      go sleep go slip go slag
>      come down oh dreaminess
>      come falling slow
>      coming falling long and slow
>      now when the leaves are falling
>      now in the **falltime** moon
>      come springerly sprangerly sprong
>      come desta poesta dreaminess
>      not at the fall of leaves
>      now in the **falltime** moon.
>      
>          ―*Poems For The People*, Carl Sandburg, published 1992, written during the **1910s**
> 3. The cornhuskers wear leather on their hands. There is no let-up to the wind. Blue bandannas are knotted at the ruddy chins. **Falltime** and winter apples take on the smolder of the five-o'clock November sunset: **falltime**, leaves, bonfires, stubble,  the old things go, and the earth is grizzled. 
>      
>          ―*Cornhuskers*, Carl Sandburg, **1918**
> 4. When we were come to the nursery, first I did show her the many baby seeds I did  gather by the wayside in the **falltime**. I did tell her how I was going to plant them  when come springtime. 
>      
>          ―*The Atlantic Monthly*.
>      Philip Gengembre Hubert, **1920**
> 5. **Falltime** is good to hear in W-Hollow. It is kindly sad, and if a body remembers the  old-timers that used to be in W-Hollow in the **falltime** and remembers the frosty  weed fields and the way they used to hunt — a body sorty wonders if the owls who-who for them in W-Hollow – them that used to be there an them there now.
>      
>          ―*Trees of Heaven*, Jesse Stuart, **1940**
> 6. **Falltime** was drawing near at hand when all the leaves would be swept off with  the fall winds and rains.
>      
>          ―*Men of the Mountains*, Jesse Stuart, **1979**
> 7. So much has changed on the reserve now. In my time there was fishing and then  hunting in the **fall time**. My mother used to tell me about her parents and I guess  they had harder times then. The men used to go in the woods in the **fall time** and and hunt all winter. They’d come home Christmas time.
>      
>          ―*Enough is Enough: Aboriginal Women Speak Out*, Janet Silman, **1988**
> 8. We came back to Carcross, 1913, **falltime**. When we got back, my aunt — my  father’s sister, Mrs. Qunaaták’ — was sick. That’s why we didn’t go anyplace, just  spent the winter in Carcross. Nineteen thirteen **falltime** she came to stay with us;  that New Year’s Eve, she died. [. . .] And I remember when they took down the *Kéet hít* — Killer Whale House — 1912 or 1913, **falltime**. [. . .] Every **falltime** we used to get a month when he’s working on a section — he worked on section for thirty-five years.
>      
>          ―*Life Lived Like a Story: Life Stories of Three Yukon Native Elders*, Julie Cruikshank, **1992**
> 9. The **falltime** “woods” sound (*tönen*) while the grove is silent (*schweigand*). “Schweigand” signals, in opposition to the “**falltime** woods,” not only reduction of color and light but also the absence of sound. 
>      
>          ―*The Mirror and the Word: Modernism, Literary Theory, and George Trakl*, Eric Williams, **1993**
> 10. When **falltime** is closing in, Inuit move elsewhere.
>       
>           ―*Uvajuq: The Origin of Death*, 
>       David F. Pelly and Kim Crockatt, **1999**
> 11. **falltime**       Autumn. “I saw her in the **falltime**.” 
>       
>           ―*American Regionalisms, Facts on File Dictionary of*, Robert Hendrickson, **2000**
> 12. “Goddamn, it’s **falltime**! They’re getting their food piles ready already." The Yukon Flats stretch for nearly three hundred miles and host perhaps two million ducks  during the summer. [. . .] “Sure feels like **falltime**. A few leaves turning yellow,” John William said.
>       
>           ―*Hoagland on Nature: Essays*, Edward Hoagland, **2003**
> 13. In the **fall time**, everyone seemed to have a lighter sense of being,  smiles all ...
>       
>           ―*Escape from Mississippi: The Diary of a Boy Growing Up in the South*, Lee Wells, **2010**
> 14. While fresh pumpkin is great for straight-up pies, we prefer the consistency and  flavor ofcanned for this insanely popular **fall-time** dessert; plus canned pumpkin  equals pumpkin cheesecake all year round.
>       
>           ―*Vegan Pie in the Sky: 75 Out-of-This-World Recipes for Pies, Tarts, Cobblers, and More*, Isa Chandra Moskowitz and Terry Hope Romero, **2011**
> 15. The **fall-time** was also a period where Northern Commercial Company needed  boat repairs. [. . .] We made journeys, especially during the **fall-time**, to the coast of go upriver in search of driftwood.
>       
>           ―*Molly Hootch: I Remember When: Growing up in Alaska on the Kwiguk Pass of the Lower Yukon River*, Molly Hootch, **2012**

I’m guessing that *fall-time* is rare even in comparison with *autumn-time* because it is likely to occur only in North American writers. It could also be that *autumn-time* may sound more “poetic” even to them.

### *Autumn time*, *Autumn-time*, *autumn-time*, and *autumntime*

Those are all the same word; after all, when spoken, they sound identical and mean the very same thing.  How this word happens to be written is merely a matter of orthographic convention, something that varies considerably across time, across publishers, and across authors.

In the double-dozen citations I give below, which illustrate a wide variety of orthographic practices, it is especially interesting when other seasons are mentioned in the same citation.

The bold emphasis is my own; it’s to help you more easily navigate the citations, which are given in chronological order as much as possible.

> 1. It was on a certain evening of the pale **Autumn time** of a certain year since the  flood, when there was a general assembling of the heavenly host.
>      
>          ―*Sad Tales and Glad Tales*, Grenville Mellen, **‎1828**
> 2. The summer has passed  away. The **autumn-time** has come. The summer-time is the season of promise;  autumn is the time of fruition. Winter, is that stillness and coldness, and  dreariness, which fortel the dawning of Hope; and *spring* is the cheering time of Hope.
>      
>          ―*The Christian Wreath: Religion, Morality, Literature*, **1847**
> 3. In the **Autumn-time** of the year, when the great metropolis is so much hotter, so much noisier, so much more dusty or so much more water-carted, so much more crowded, so much more disturbing and distracting in all respects, than it usually is, a quiet sea-beach becomes indeed a blessed spot.
>          ―*Our English Watering-Place*, Charles Dickens, **1851**
> 4. The day broke mistily (it was **autumn time**), and I could not disembarrass myself of the idea that I had to climb those heights and banks of cloud, and that there was an Alpine Convent somewhere behind the sun, where I was going to breakfast. 
>          ―*The Uncommercial Traveller*, Charles Dickens, **1861**
> 5. And when the autumn comes the flowers to fade
>      As the man faded: then he thinks of death,
>      Which makes the **autumntime** seem  melancholy. 
>      And this was **autumntime**, so my own memories
>      And thoughts went  to the music of the year—
>      To the sad music of eternity, 
>    And death — as  everything did die.
>      
>          ―*My first book, named otherwise: Lispings, yearnings and mutterings*, Levi Belcher, **1873**
> 6. Margie had wished for spring violets, and he had given her these, obtained that  day from a hothouse, where the tropical atmosphere had deceived the little blue-eyed things into thinking the chilly **autumn-time** was blossoming May.
>      
>          ―*Ballou’s Monthly Magazine*, “The Fatal Glove: –or– The History of a Chimney-Sweeper”, Clara Augusta, **1875**
> 7. Now is the Spring of Love, yet soon will come
>      On meadow and tree the Summer’s lordly bloom;
>      And soon the grass with brighter flowers will blow,
>      And send up lilies for some boy to mow.
>      Then before long the Summer’s conqueror,
>      Rich **Autumn-time**, the season’s usurer,
>      Will lend his hoarded gold to all the trees,
>      And see it scattered by the spendthrift breeze; 
>      And after that the Winter cold and drear. 
>      So runs the perfect cycle of the year.
>      
>          ―“Ravenna”, Oscar Wilde, **1878**
> 8. Another day dawned and closed, and another; the blossomed wheatears set, and the ears plumped out and  absorbed the sunlight till they too fell beneath the scythe, and deep peace of the  mellow **autumn-time** lay upon meadow, wood, and sea.
>      
>          ―*The Last Sentence*, 
>      Maxwell Gray, **‎1892**
> 9. Coming to this **autumn time**, the Christian, as we have found him, longs for the  soul’s home.
>      
>          ―*The Christian Evangelist*, **1904**
> 10. The passionate music of wild birds’ songs plays upon the strings of the one heart,  which is the mother heart of each and both. In the **autumntime**, when the tyrant “Jack Frost” comes and causes this tree to “furl her sails” and go into winter quarters, one by one the beautiful leaves turn red, then brown, then loosen their hold and flutter to earth.
>       
>           ―*Sunshine and Shadow: Some Promiscuous Writings*,
>       John Logan Jones, **‎1909**
> 11. “What a queer way of living!” thought Striped Chipmunk.  “It’s all very well to have a snug house under the ground, where one can sleep the long cold winter away and be perfectly safe, but what any one wants to live under the ground all the time for, in the beautiful springtime and summertime and **autumntime**, I can’t understand.  Just think of all that Miner misses — the sunshine, the flowers, the songs of the birds, and the Merry Little Breezes to play with!  I wonder—”
>       
>           ―*Mother West Wind “Why” Stories*,
>       Thornton Waldo Burgess, **‎1915**
> 12. It is a Saturday afternoon of  blue and yellow **autumn-time**, and the scene is the High Street of a well-known  market-town.
>       
>           ―*The Works of Thomas Hardy in Prose and Verse*,
>       Thomas Hardy, **‎1920**
> 13. And see great, void,
>       tree-clad hills piling behind one another, from nowhere into
>       nowhere.  They were green in **autumn time**.
>       
>           ―*The Woman Who Rode Away and other stories*, DH Lawrence, **1928**
> 14. In **autumntime**, Ovid explains (II, 315–336), the girl’s health may be affected by  rapid shifts of hot and cold weather.
>       
>           ―*Ovid: A Poet Between Two Worlds*, Hermann Ferdinand Fränkel, **‎1945**
> 15. On each occasion when **autumn-time** came round, they put to shore, sowed  grain in the soil of whatever part of Libya they had reached on their voyage, and waited until reaping-time. 
>       
>           ―*The Cambridge History of the British Empire* (Volume II), Eric 
>       Anderson Walker, **‎1963**
> 16. Once upon a time that tree had dropped its burden of nuts in the **autumn-time**.
>       
>           ―*No Time for Tears*, June Masters Bacher, **1992**
> 17. If I never get to Mexico to see them in their overwintering sites, I can at least look forward  to a continual feast of monarch butterfly beauty during their summer and early **autumn time** here on our mountain. 
>       
>           ―*Appalacian Autumn*, Marcia Bonta, **1994**
> 18. It is composed of height of ponderosa, breadth of valley,  depth of stream, wintertime, summertime, springtime, **autumntime**, the vanilla  smell of Jeffery pine, the gritty taste of granite, the puckery taste of alpine sorrel, the unexpected song of a canyon wren, the senses of time, the waterfalls of the mind.
>       
>           ―*Natural State: A Literary Anthology of California Nature Writing*,
>       Steven Gilbar, **‎1998**
> 19. The springtime full moon has a much different luminescence than the **autumntime**  full moon.
>       
>           ―*Cunt: A Declaration of Independence*,
>       Inga Muscio, **2002**
> 20. Surely the wintertime of human life must have its own special rewards, not just a  pitiful appendage to **autumntime**.
>       
>           ―*Facing Death: Theme and Variations*,
>       F. David Martin, **‎2006**
> 21. Along with the inexorable process of letting go, this season holds a great sense  of quality and meaning, which is apparent on a quiet stroll in the forest during the **autumntime**.
>       
>           ―*Archetypal Acupuncture: Healing with the Five Elements*, Gary Dolowich, **‎2011**
> 22. Well, forgotten except by the town kids who sometimes went up there, mainly in the  summer: there was no-one around at **autumntime**, except me, Daz and Simon – and they’ll all tell you at the High School that we’re crazy.
>       
>           ―*Catch and Other Stories*, Steve Bowkett, **2012**
> 23. Above all, it was believed that plague prevailed during the autumn: **Autumn-time**  was called “our enemy” and “the slayer of many men” because this was the  season that was seen as being more changeable, humid and windy, and it was then that the summer’s head might linger and yet the sun, being lower in the sky, was not as effective in terms of burning up the air’s moistures with its deflected rays.
>       
>           ―*An Environmental History of the Middle Ages: The Crucible of Nature*, John Aberth, **‎2012**
> 24. Acorns and beech mast are real favourites, and jays become very active, and  slightly less wary, around **autumntime** when food is abundant.
>       
>           ―*Hunting with Air Rifles: The Complete Guide*, Matthew Manning, **2014**

Comment: Yes. Both answers to this question were fascinating, but here in the UK I say autumn-time, and have heard it said by others.

Comment: +1, a thorough answer. I would only quibble with the statement "absence of evidence never constitutes evidence of absence," which I would amend to "absence of evidence is not *necessarily* evidence of absence." There are many cases (e.g. in experimental particle physics) where absence of evidence of a particular phenomenon where expected is interpreted as evidence of its absence, even if not as conclusive evidence by itself. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evidence_of_absence

Comment: P.S. As you once said (http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96697/why-don-t-we-write-poetry-like-beowulf-any-longer), "if it cannot be easily demonstrated, then it may well not be true." ;-)

Answer (score 1):

One reason why autumn time was not accepted in standard use is that the Latin word is already ready-made for harvest time. I suppose that the etymology of the Latin word is altum tempus which changed to autum+..m.us which changed to autumnus. As altum tempus means already high time a word formation such as "high time-time" is not very convincing.

BNC, a British corpus with material from the later part of the 20th century onwards, has no incidents for autumntime, autumn time, and autumn-time.

Comment: The oldest for of *autumnus* in Latin is *auctumnus,* which doesn't seem to agree with your etymology.  [See Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/autumnus).